# How to compare two columns of two different files

Tags: linux, search, awk, comparison, string

I have two file.The first one contains something like:

```
a.com,5,some,text
b.com,10,some,text
c.com,5,some,text
d.com,12,some,text
e.com,5,some,text
c.com,5,some,text
```

The second contains something like:

```
c.com,5,some,text
d.com,12,some,text
a.com,5,some,text
b.com,10,some,text
e.com,5,some,text
c.com,5,some,text
```

I want to sort, compare the first two columns of the two files. I assume they should be similar. If there is any difference I want to know where is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bash:

```
diff <(sort file1 | cut -d , -f 1-2) <(sort file2 | cut -d , -f 1-2)
```

But `diff` will only see two columns, so its output (if there is a difference) will be limited to them. I don't know if this is acceptable to you.

This simple solution will fail if your files [handle commas, quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769675) etc. In this case more specialized tools should be used (e.g. import the files to a spreadsheet and work there).

Comment: My first two columns format is similar to the similar example I posted.